# Selectively use_framework! in cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I wish I can compile some pods into dynamic frameworks while keeping others as static frameworks.

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'A'
pod 'B'
pod 'C'
```

By default the `use_frameworks!` option is an all or none approach. I wonder if we can opt out some of the frameworks from being compiled dynamically.

For example, how can I make pod `A` compiled into dynamic framework while keeping `B` and `C` static libraries? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible with CocoaPods. One option would be to include your static libraries manually, and include your other dependencies as frameworks through CocoaPods. Although this is not ideal.